# "For what" vs "what....for"

Tags: word-order, questions

> **For what** did I pay you 500 dollars more?
>
> **What** did I pay you 500 dollars more **for**?

Are both of these questions grammatical?

Comment: Yes, they are both grammatical.

Comment: They are both fine.  The first one is a little more formal.   "What.. for" is a little more typical in spoken English.  Don't believe any one who tells you that you can't end a sentence (especially a question) with a **preposition**.  [1](http://www.ronslate.com/on-dreyers-english-an-utterly-correct-guide-to-clarity-and-style-by-benjamin-dreyer/) [2](https://www.wbur.org/hereandnow/2019/03/05/benjamin-dreyer-grammar-guide)

Comment: and "I paid you 500 dollars more.  **For what?**" is also grammatical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commenters said, both of these are grammatically acceptable.

> For what did I pay you 500 dollars?

Sounds antiquated and very formal, but it is not wrong. This sort of sentence would be found in classic literature, such as that from the 19th century, or in highly formal writing, such as business contract negotiations.

> What did I pay you 500 dollars for?

Sounds modern. People use this sort of wording frequently in speaking and writing.